# Docker-compose overwriting package.json

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to run a simple react app using Dockerfile and docker-compose. However  when I run the command docker-compose up, it fails with error that package.json doesn't exist. I guess the docker volume mount is somehow overwriting this file.

Can someone please tell me any workaround to it.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /apps
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  react-app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /apps/node_modules
      - ./:/apps
```

Output

```
docker-compose up --build
Building react-app
Step 1/6 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> ebbf98230a82
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /apps
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 52ab3e742158
Step 3/6 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b88a10e48c6f
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1da097307540
Step 5/6 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c748991eb661
Step 6/6 : CMD ["npm","run","start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e138b3c17689
Successfully built e138b3c17689
Successfully tagged frontend_react-app:latest
Starting 86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 ... done
Attaching to 86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR! path /apps/package.json
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR! code ENOENT
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR! errno -2
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR! syscall open
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/apps/package.json'
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR! enoent
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 |
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-12T14_36_59_257Z-debug.log
86e0c20b7955_frontend_react-app_1 exited with code 254
```

Folder Structure

```
--node_modules
--package.json
--Dockerfile.dev
--Docker-compose.yml
```

EDIT---

Trying to make my app react to changes in the source code without the need to rebuild the image. For this I need this bind mount to work.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, you overwrite your `/app` directory when launching the stuff.

You are using **bind mount**, which in opposite to **volume** always overwrites the container's folder with contents of the host's folder.

I doubt you need this mount - you app is being copied on build stage. Just remove this line from `docker-compose.yml` and enjoy.

Comment: I am trying to make my app react to any changes in the source code without the need to rebuild everything. For that I need mount to work. Also, the host folder itself is having package.json file. So how come it's not getting detected ??
Can you suggest something which will make this work please.

Comment: Such behavior seems to be counter to how one would normally use containers. Why is this a requirement for your application?

Comment: Just trying to learn binding mounts. I am not doing this in a PRD environment.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why but doing below in my docker-compose.yml file worked for me.

```
volumes:
      - '.:/apps/'
      - /apps/node_modules/
```

Basically, I enclosed the first mount in single quotes  :p